# Finding a Encryption Algorithm to encrypt users personal data

Tags: algorithm, encryption

There are personal service need encrypt user's data only archived by his password which able to make database saved as secret data.It is meaningful I can make sure the software developer and manager can't get users data.
It's easy that I can choice a algorithm to let user's password as factor link it to the encrypted data.But how about user change his password? On the one hand, I can't save user's password straightly(password encrypted by `md5` which is irreversible), on the other hand, I can't encrypt data again if password changed.
Does it able to do?Thanks

**UPDATE**
I hit by the situation when user forget his password.It seems my presupposition was unreality.>_<
Please consider it I haven't think of any idea.
Make the question fallback to "How to use encrypted data in database make sure only data owner can achieve it."
If not consider forget password, @samgak give a good idea at question comment.
And now, can I continue use users password as the key or find another way to deal with the new problem?

Comment: please note that a simple md5 hash for password storage is not the best choice: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure.

Comment: Is the encryption/decryption happening on server side or on user's PC after receiving encrypted data from server? How much user data is there? If it's a small amount you can just decrypt with old password and re-encrypt with new password if they change it. If it's large then one solution is to encrypt data with a random key and then store the key in a file encrypted with the user's password. When they change their password just change this file, the random key and encrypted data doesn't need to change.

Comment: "encrypted with user's password" = "encrypted with a key securely derived from the user's password"

Comment: @samgak, Thanks for your advice, save a random key to file it a good idea. for you ask, encryption/decryption happens on server side,client is bowser. and I consider encrypt data is amount so I should avoid encrypt it again.

Comment: @samgak, a another problem strikes me.How about user forget his password?Because re-encrypt the encrypted random key need former password to decryption. >.<

Comment: I think that's impossible with your requirements. If you can reset the password, it means the original password isn't needed to decrypt the data. In that case the developer or manager can read the data by triggering a password reset.